# Reference to pointer (int * const & arg)

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

What is this exactly:

```
int * const & arg
```

Is this

- a reference to an int pointer?
- a reference to a const int pointer?
- a const reference to an int pointer?
- a const reference to an const int pointer?

By the way, const references does not make any sense to me. I thought you can not change references after they are declared...

Comment: Read from right to left. Reference to a constant pointer to a (non-const) int

Comment: ... which is the same thing as a `const` reference to a pointer to (non-`const`) `int`, right?  Certainly it's a reference to a pointer either way, and it cannot be used to modify the pointer to which it refers, but it *can* be used to modify the `int` to which the pointer points..

Comment: @JohnBollinger There is no such thing as a `const` reference.  There is just a reference.  And by definition, a reference cannot be changed, so yes, it is *effectively* const.  And yes, in this case, the pointer is `const` and cannot be changed to point at another `int`, but the `int` itself is not `const` and so its value can be freely changed via the pointer/reference.

Comment: You are correct. You can't change which object the reference refers to.  The `const` in the case refers to the data at the referenced object. It cannot be changed. Eg given `int val = 13; const int & ref = val;`, you cannot `ref = 42;` to change the value of `val`. You could still `val = 42;` because `val`'s not `const`. You just cannot use the reference to change `val`

Comment: The words "const reference" are commonly used when people really mean "reference to const". (Doesn't bother me as long as the context isn't a very technical one and we're not talking directly about what the reference or the type means.)

Comment: @RemyLebeau: And yet "treat target as readonly" is a property of the reference, not the pointer it refers to.  Use of this reference will only permit reading the pointer, but it does not mean the pointer actually is `const`.  Some other piece of code can perfectly well change that pointer.

Comment: @BenVoigt in this case, the `const` DOES apply to the pointer being referenced. The pointer is readonly only because the pointer is `const`. The only way other code could change the pointer is if 1) the original pointer were non-`const` but were assigned to a `const` variable/parameter which the reference then refers to, or 2) the other code casts away the `const`

Comment: @RemyLebeau: The *lvalue* accessing the pointer is readonly.  The pointer object to which the reference refers / that *lvalue* accesses does not need to be const.  The way other code could change the pointer is if (1) the original pointer is non-`const`.  There is no (2) since casting away `const` is allowed if and only if (1), and there is no restriction or requirement of an assignment.  You can directly do `int* p; int* const& r = p;`  There is no `const` variable or parameter here at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

arg is a **reference** to an **int pointer**, where that pointer **itself** is constant.

When declaring arg, you will notice that (because it is a reference) it must be initialized, as references cannot reference nothing.

An easy way to see this is by using an example:

```
int x;
int* const ptr = &x;
// declare an integer pointer which is constant i.e. the address it stores does not change,
// and initialize this address to the address of x

int* const& arg = ptr;
// declare a reference variable called arg, which references an integer pointer which is constant,
// the same type that ptr is, and then make it reference our ptr variable
```

Since the **const** argument is after the "*" in your line of code, you are telling C++ that the pointer itself is constant. However, if we were to write either

```
const int* & arg = ...
```

or

```
int const* & arg = ...
```

we would be telling C++ that the pointer is pointing to data (in this case an integer) which is constant. Further, if we wrote the following

```
int const* const & arg = ...
```

we would be telling C++ that the address the pointer stores is constant, and that this address points to an integer which is also constant.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

> Is this
>
> a reference to an int pointer?

No, because there is const.

> a reference to a const int pointer?

Yes. It is better to use the same order as the declaration except in reverse to be clear: A

```
reference to a const pointer to int.
&              const *          int
```

Compared to the original, non reverse order:

```
int * const &
```

> a const reference to an int pointer?
>
> a const reference to an const int pointer?

There is technically no such thing as "const reference".

Although often people use it to mean reference to const. With such interpretation, a const reference to an int pointer is same as a reference to const int pointer. Also, with such interpretation, const reference to const has meaningless repetition of const.

Comment: There is no such type as a "reference to const` either.  The type formed by using those grammar productions together gives you a reference which only allows reading its target, the target itself may or may not really be `const`.

Comment: @BenVoigt It is not a type. It is a category of types. A reference to const int is a reference to const, just like a reference to const char is. And indeed, a reference to const T can refer to non-const T.

Comment: Agreed about the category or family of types, disagree about "reference to const int".  There is no such thing.  `int const&` is a reference to an int which yields a read-only lvalue.  There is no guarantee that the `int` is `const` immutable.  Such a reference binds perfectly happily to a non-`const` `int`.  The `lvalue` is `const`, the target object is not known to be.  It is a reference providing readonly access to an `int`, not a reference providing access to a `const int`.

Comment: @BenVoigt If there is no such thing as "reference to const T", then why does the C++ standard repeatedly use such term?

Comment: Thanks for helping!